# Core Data retrieve detailed information

Tags: ios, core-data, entity-relationship

[image: Core Data]

Hello, i'm trying to take detailed information from the database, i create a simple database, and i display the Grocery attribute fruit in a table view for example:
Apple
Grapes
Strawberry
Melon
...
if i click on the apple row for example,i want retrieve the details information for that object: so i want see only the the fruitName grouped for fruitID, for example there are a lot of apple fruit type, and every type have a id...so i want see only the apple Type for a ID, i hope i'm explain well the problem.

i found only this method:

```
- (NSArray *)sortFruit {
NSSortDescriptor *sortLastNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"fruitID" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortLastNameDescriptor, nil];
return [[[fruit valueForKey:@"detailes"] allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
}
```

but in this way i can only take all detail for that fruit, and sorted by fruitID, but i can't choose a value...so i can't see only a specific fruitID group...

**EDIT:** Thank you very much for the answer, ok now in this way:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate
                          predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@",
                          @"fruitID", [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
NSArray *arrayfiletered = [[self sortEpisode] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

i can retrieve the info for a specific fruitID, but there is a way to see how many different fruitID there are for that fruit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you want is in the NSPredicate class.  See specifically the function [filteredArrayWithPredicate:](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/filteredArrayUsingPredicate%3a) in the NSArray class.  It will return a new array based on the predicate that you pass in.  [This](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html) is an article about how to use predicates.

Comment: Sorry your question has become a little unclear to me.  You want to fetch a "Grocery" and see how many "Details" is has?

Comment: no i want fetch "Grocery" and see how many different fruitID there are for that fruitGrocery...

Comment: According to your image above, fruitID is an attribute of Detail, so if you know the number of Details, it is the same as the number of fruitIDs.

Comment: Um...I don't really understand.  Just fetch the grocery object, and loop through each of the objects in `detailes`